# Scrape all tables from div using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I needed to extract the `<tr>` tags from all tables in the `<div id="specs-list">`. However it is just fetches only the top six tables. Here is the [page](http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_k3_note-7147.php). Here is my code.

```
def getPhoneStats(url):
    urls={}
    try:
        request= requests.get(url)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            sourceCode = BeautifulSoup(request.content,"html.parser")
            tables = sourceCode.select('#specs-list table')
            for table in tables:
                tag = table.find('tr')
                print(tag.get_text())
        else:
            print('no table or row found ')
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        print('Unable to open url',e)
```

It just prints till the 6th table of the div :

```
Network
Technology
GSM / HSPA / LTE


Launch
Announced
2015, March


Body
Dimensions
152.6 x 76.2 x 8 mm (6.01 x 3.00 x 0.31 in)


Display
Type
IPS capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors


Platform
OS
Android OS, v5.0.2 (Lollipop), upgradable to v6.0 (Marshmallow)


Memory
Card slot
microSD, up to 32 GB (dedicated slot)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML is malformed. THe "Memory" table has too many /td and /tr tags at the end. I think that is messing with the parser. I had better luck skipping the div and looking directly for the tables:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 


def getPhoneStats(url):
    try:
        request= requests.get(url)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content,"html.parser")

            for table in soup.findAll("table"):
                header = table.th.get_text()
                for row in table.findAll("tr"):
                    out_row = [ header ]
                    for col in row.findAll("td"):
                        out_row.append(col.get_text())
                    print(out_row)
        else:
            print('unable to connect ')
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        print('Unable to open url',e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    getPhoneStats('''http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_k3_note-7147.php''')
```

Which gave the results:

```
['Network', 'Technology', 'GSM / HSPA / LTE']
['Network', '2G bands', 'GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 - SIM 1 & SIM 2']
['Network', '\xa0', 'GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 - SIM 1 & SIM 2 - India']
['Network', '3G bands', 'HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100 ']
['Network', '\xa0', 'HSDPA 2100 - India']
['Network', '4G bands', 'LTE band 1(2100), 3(1800), 7(2600), 38(2600), 39(1900), 40(2300), 41(2500)']
['Network', 'Speed', 'HSPA, TD-SCDMA, LTE, TD-LTE']
['Network', 'GPRS', 'Yes']
['Network', 'EDGE', 'Yes']
['Launch', 'Announced', '2015, March']
['Launch', 'Status', 'Available. Released 2015, March']
['Body', 'Dimensions', '152.6 x 76.2 x 8 mm (6.01 x 3.00 x 0.31 in)']
['Body', 'Weight', '150 g (5.29 oz)']
['Body', 'SIM', 'Dual SIM (Micro-SIM, dual stand-by)']
['Display', 'Type', 'IPS capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors']
['Display', 'Size', '5.5 inches (~71.7% screen-to-body ratio)']
['Display', 'Resolution', '1080 x 1920 pixels (~401 ppi pixel density)']
['Display', 'Multitouch', 'Yes, up to 5 fingers']
['Display', '\xa0', '- Lenovo Vibe 2.0']
['Platform', 'OS', 'Android OS, v5.0.2 (Lollipop), upgradable to v6.0 (Marshmallow)']
['Platform', 'Chipset', 'Mediatek MT6752']
['Platform', 'CPU', 'Octa-core 1.7 GHz Cortex-A53']
['Platform', 'GPU', 'Mali-T760MP2']
['Memory', 'Card slot', 'microSD, up to 32 GB (dedicated slot)']
['Memory', 'Internal', '16 GB, 2 GB RAM']
['Camera', 'Primary', '13 MP, f/2.0, autofocus, dual-LED flash, check quality']
['Camera', 'Features', 'Geo-tagging, touch focus, face detection, HDR, panorama']
['Camera', 'Video', '1080p@30fps, check quality']
['Camera', 'Secondary', '5 MP, f/2.4']
['Sound', 'Alert types', 'Vibration; MP3, WAV ringtones']
['Sound', 'Loudspeaker ', 'Yes']
['Sound', '3.5mm jack ', 'Yes']
['Sound', '\xa0', '- Dolby Atmos']
['Comms', 'WLAN', 'Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n, hotspot']
['Comms', 'Bluetooth', 'v4.1, A2DP, LE']
['Comms', 'GPS', 'Yes, with A-GPS, GLONASS']
['Comms', 'Radio', 'FM radio']
['Comms', 'USB', 'microUSB v2.0, USB Host']
['Features', 'Sensors', 'Accelerometer, gyro, proximity, compass']
['Features', 'Messaging', 'SMS(threaded view), MMS, Email, Push Mail, IM']
['Features', 'Browser', 'HTML5']
['Features', 'Java', 'No']
['Features', '\xa0', '- Active noise cancellation with dedicated mic\r\n- MP4/H.264 player\r\n- MP3/WAV/eAAC+/FLAC player\r\n- Photo/video editor\r\n- Document viewer']
['Battery', '\xa0', 'Removable Li-Ion 3000 mAh battery']
['Battery', 'Stand-by', 'Up to 750 h (3G)']
['Battery', 'Talk time', 'Up to 36 h (3G)']
['Misc', 'Colors', 'Onyx Black, Pearl White, Laser Yellow']
['Misc', 'Price group', '3/10 (About 150 EUR)']
['Tests', 'Performance', '\nBasemark OS II: 1053 / Basemark OS II 2.0: 984Basemark X: 5656']
['Tests', 'Display', '\nContrast ratio: 1793:1 (nominal)']
['Tests', 'Camera', '\nPhoto / Video']
['Tests', 'Loudspeaker', '\nVoice 65dB / Noise 66dB / Ring 76dB\n']
['Tests', 'Battery life', '\n\nEndurance rating 53h\n\n']
['Tests']
```

Next time, please post code that I can run (like my example).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the imports were not there. This works

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue with the html parser.  I prefer using the html5lib, but it's slower, so if speed is important, one of the C based parsers may be better (read more [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser))

I just changed `sourceCode = BeautifulSoup(request.content,"html.parser")` to be `sourceCode = BeautifulSoup(request.content,"html5lib")` and it was good to go (full updated code below).

Also, I'm not sure if you noticed this, but by using the `tag = table.find('tr')` line, you're only returning the first line of each table grouping.  If you want the full table, just `print(table.get_text()` in the for loop

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, html5lib
def getPhoneStats(url):
    urls={}
    try:
        request= requests.get(url)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            sourceCode = BeautifulSoup(request.content,'html5lib')
            tables = sourceCode.select('#specs-list table')
            for table in tables:
                #tag = table.find('tr')
                #print(tag.get_text())
                print(table.get_text())
        else:
            print('no table or row found ')
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        print('Unable to open url',e)
```